# Can every character apply untrained skills without limitation?

Tags: skills, actions, pathfinder-2e

With 'trained only' skills it is obvious, but I am not sure whether everybody can use all other skills even without being an expert in it.
Let us take as an example the 'Palming an object' action within the 'Thievery' Skill.
Or let us take Arcana 'Recall Knowledge' action as a second one. I think in Pathfinder 1e the max you could roll on Knowledge Skills was a DC10 when you are not having any Skill Points in it.
Do we still have such limitations in PF 2e?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There is no penalty on untrained skill checks.

The rules for training skills are found on page 233 (see the Skill Actions heading). It says:

> Anyone can use a skill's untrained actions, but you can use trained actions only if you have a proficiency rank of trained or better in that skill.

You can read the entire section, but there is no penalty of any kind for being untrained.Effectively, the penalty is that you can't apply a proficiency bonus.

The only limitation on the *kinds* of checks is what you already mentioned: you may not attempt Trained actions unless you are well, trained. Untrained actions can be used without restriction.